# Find object where value is equal to set value

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope `$scope.moviesCheck` that contains many objects. I would like to return one object inside that scope that equals a value in another scope.

For example, In my `$scope.moviesCheck` I have 8 objects. Each object in that scope has a string called `movie_id` with values 1-8.

I also have a scope `$scope.movieListID.id`. This scope has a value of 1-8. Now I want to check the `$scope.moviesCheck` scope, to find a object that has the same string value as `$scope.movieListID.id` and then return that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
var objList=$scope.moviesCheck.filter(function(x){ return x.movie_id == $scope.movieListID.id; });

var obj = objList.length > 0 ? objList[0] : {};

console.log(obj);
```